# Removing empty entry in List<dynamic> that only shows while inspecting

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list that I am getting the values from an API,
it is `List<dynamic>` type, while I `print` it I am getting this output (for example): `[cat, female]`, but when I use `inspect` it has three values: `"cat", "female", ""`. The last empty value is making some problems in my code, so I wanted to remove it, but I don't know how to do this.
As it is a `List<dynamic>` I used `removeLast()` and also `toString()` but none of them worked for me. I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to filter items and get the new list:

```dart
final newList = list.where((e) => e != null && e != '').toList();
```

`removeLast()` does not work as you expected. If you read the comment of the method it says `Removes and returns the last object in this list.`

PS: I recommend you use a functional way to deal with a list which means do not modify the state of the original list instead, get a new list.